# How do I manually set nested model values in Rails 3 before saving?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, nested-attributes

I have a single text area input that I would like to get as a blob my `new` method on my controller, but would like to parse and otherwise mess with the input before it's saved.

I know I can arbitrarily set attributes on a model by saying something like

```
@post.user_id = current_user.id
```

where that attribute isn't coming directly from a form. My issue here though is that I want to set a nested model's values.

Let's say the association is `post has_many comments` and `comment belongs_to post`

Does `post.comments` just get set to a hash that looks like comments? Like

```
@post.comment = {'comment' => 'foo'}
```

Or something similar?

Thanks for any guidance on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have nested form fors, you can just get the comment values from your params via:

```
@post.comment.update_attributes(params[:comment])
```

(you should have called @post.build_comment in your #new though)

If you're looking to set them in your controller, then you need a hash 'container' for your comment like so:

```
{'comment' => {:message => 'foo', :author => current_user}}
```

or something like that

Answer (score 2):

Usually I'd say it's best to DRY up this sort of thing and just handle the parsing on the comments model itself with a `before_save` callback.

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :parse_comment

  protected
  def parse_comment
    self.comment = ...
  end
end
```

But if a callback isn't going to work for you, @corroded's suggestion should work.